# Does Python define formal behavior for platform functions "Availability"

Tags: python-3.x, cross-platform, documentation, compatibility

I'm creating cross-platform Python application, so I need to pay attention to the official disclaimers related to platform availability. For example:

> os.getlogin()
>
> ...
>
> **Availability**: Unix, Windows, not Emscripten, not WASI.

Unfortunatly I couldn't figure it out what "Unavailable" is in program behavior for wide spectr of functins (not only `getlogin()`).

1. Is there some standard exception to distinguish "Unavailable" case?
2. Is it enough to always wrap invocation with `try...except StandardError` to provide failover?
3. Do I need hide `import` with `try` as well or it is enough for function invocation? In other words:

```
try:
    import os
    os.getlogin()
    ...
except StandardError: # platform doesn't support user recognition
    ...
```

VS

```
import os
try:
    os.getlogin()
    ...
except StandardError: # platform doesn't support user recognition
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will simply get an `AttributeError`. For example, on MacOS ([`set_handle_inheritable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.set_handle_inheritable) is only available on Windows):

```py
>>> os.get_handle_inheritable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'get_handle_inheritable'
```

So you can either:

- Just `import os` and check the OS before every usage
- Try to import the individual methods and catch `ImportError`
- Try to call the functions and catch `AttributeError`